# Getting quick text onto a windows 32 window C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Rather than having to load in DirectX etc etc yada yada, I wondered if there was a quick and dirty way of getting some text up into my window?

Comment: Yes. Just use TextOut or DrawText.

Comment: Not exactly dirty, but [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498.aspx) will do.

Comment: Both of these answers are part of the Win32 GUI API. This may or may not be what you want if you need portability or if you want something that is a little bit less dry than that API.

Comment: @Alexandre How did you read *portability* into the *winapi* tag? Or the mention of DirectX.

Comment: OP does not seem to be very familiar with the subject. I assumed he may not know what API is or is not portable.

Comment: But, but, `DrawText` can't make 3D text :D

Comment: haha, got the Drawtext working thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This will probably get closed (way too broad question).

You can use the "native" Win32 GUI API on Windows and there are libraries (some portable, others not) which serve just that purpose like Gtk, wxWidget, etc. The choice of technology alone is not so simple.

Here is an intro to Win32 GUI API which was considered good when I was into this.

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, you've answered my question.